# Delele shortcut linking to non-existing file

Tags: windows, vbscript, jscript

Here's my problem: I need to write a script deleting shortcuts that are linking to non-existing files and shows which shortcuts were deleted.
Script on JScript or VBScript (Windows Script Host)

How can I get, if shortcut links to non-existent files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can open a shortcut by (re-)creating it. Then you can use the `FileExists` method to check if the `TargetPath` exists.

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set sh  = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

For Each f In fso.GetFolder("C:\path\to\shortcuts").Files
  If LCase(fso.GetExtensionName(f.Name)) = "lnk" Then
    Set lnk = sh.CreateShortcut(f.Path)
    If Not fso.FileExists(lnk.TargetPath) Then
      WScript.Echo "Deleting shortcut '" & f.Path & "'."
      f.Delete
    End If
  End If
Next
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you! The only question is: writing this script on JScript (for practice) is the same way as on vbs? Same functions and same methods?

Comment: When in doubt, [read](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xsy6k3ys) the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9ty6h50).